# sql - How can I extract all information through one statement from 3 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables.

**First one:**

Stores(`StoreID`, `Name`)

**Second one:**

Store_Items(`StoreID`, `ItemID`)

**Third one:**

Items(`ItemID`, `Name`, `Price`)

How can I write a single statement, which get `all StoreID` and `all names` and `all items for each StoreID`?

Should I use Join or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from Store as S
    left outer join Store_Items as SI on SI.StoreID = S.StoreID
    left outer join Items as I on I.ItemID = SI.ItemID
```

Comment: maybe redundant `on I.ItemID`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   select s.storeid, s.name, si.itemid, i.name, i.price
     from store s
left join store_item si on si.storeid = s.storeid
left join item i on i.itemid = store.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should join the tables roughly as such

```
SELECT * FROM `firstone`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `secondone`
ON firstone.StoreId = secondone.StoreID
LEFT OUTER JOIN `thirdone`
ON secondone.ItemID = thirdone.ItemID
```